# How to disable public holidays on data picker with laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel

I'm new to laravel. I want to make public holidays disabled in an appointment schedule application such that customers will not be allowed to book for an appointment during such period.

For example, if the date is Thursday, December 26, 2019, it should return: today is boxing day, you can't book an appointment today please schedule an appointment for another day. Please, how can I achieve that in laravel?

Comment: This is more of a question regarding the Datepicker plugin you're using and not Laravel. You should include the code used to init your picker, along with which one you're using. By default, I'm not aware of any that have this capability and may need to implement a lot of custom logic to return dates with descriptions.

Comment: You need to be more specific about your problem. What did you try? Can you show us some code? Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to improve it. Thank you!

Comment: Laravel is a backend framework, whereas your question seems more related to frontend. Can you explain how you're displaying the date to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is to validate the date you receive from your form in your laravel backend server, there are several libraries out there you can try. Take a look at https://github.com/checkdomain/Holiday